# How to fetch data from google analytics funnel visualization?

Tags: google-analytics

I am using GA API for java to access data from GA. I need to fetch values from funnel visualization for example: "Cart" value. If any one knows regarding the same then I need your help..

Thanks,
Vipin Dhiman

Answer (score 0):

The funnel visualization is just constructed out of unique pageviews to a URL. So if you know the steps in the process, you can just make the calls to GA and then do the calculations yourself at each step. Then if you need something like exit pages, or something like that, you can make another call with the correct dimension, like ga:nextPagePath to see where people are going at each step.